# How to avoid no Captcha re Captcha audio only in English?

Tags: internationalization, accessibility, recaptcha

I want to implement the [noCaptcha reCaptcha](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/index.html) in a major latin american website.
 Everything works ok except the audio challenge.

The audio challenge is **only** in English and this is a problem for only native Spanish speaking people. Besides that, the audio quality is low so it's harder for people with basic English knowledge.

I would like to disable the audio challenge but didn't find a way to do this. If the audio is disabled it's a penalty for people with visual disabilities, but audio challenge in English only is a roadblock.

I didn't find a place to submit a request to the Google's team behind no Captcha.

Are there others implementation of catpchas like Google without this cultural problem?

Is there any turnaround to avoid this issue with Google implementation?